# Ad-hoc distribution in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, distribution, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a problem, I've got ad-hoc distribution povisioning profile. I have done all procedure 
product/archive and there are only two buttons validate and distribute and NO share button.

What to do? I followed this tutorial http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/ But there no button share.

I tried to click distribute then chose save for enterprise or ad-hoc distribution then saved it but ipa file doesn't work on IPhone(.

Please help me.

Comment: In what way does it not work on the iPhone? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I posted an answer for it, please let me know which part you are missing so I can add more details for it.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to make it simple for you:

1. Collect UDID for each iPhone/iPad you have then login to the provisioning profile and open the Devices page and add them.
2. Generate distribution certificate from the provisioning portal
3. Create new APP ID with bundle ID
4. Create ad-doc dist. profile
5. login to iTunes Connect and create the App details
6. download and install the ad-hoc profile and the certificate you generated.
7. configure your xcode project to referee to the bundle id and sign the build with the profile you just installed.
8. archive the project and distribute it through www.testflightapp.com or just send the ipa file to the testers so they can install it through iTunes.
9. TestFlightApp will make your life easier and save you time telling the testers how to download the ipa through the itunes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the UUID of the device you are trying to install to registered to your developer account and added to your ad-hoc provisioning profile?

Is the build configuration used for archiving set to use this provisioning profile?

When you archived to a .ipa, did you try to install it through iTunes?