# Nothing worked! certificates and provisioning turned my life into a living hell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I'm not actually new here, I've been reviewing a lot of Q&A, especially lately..

I'm having issues in my Certification & Uploading to app store..

I've done everything I saw here to resolve my issue.

Basically, none of my certificates (even newly created) work when I try to archive my projects.
I try distribution ones, it says :"no unexpired provisioning profiles found"
I try developer ones just for the heck of it, it either says: "no identities were available for signing" or "administrator must request identities..."

I'm pretty much sure I've created the appropriate distribution certificates & provisioning profile, App ID & all the work related to keychaing & installing profiles on Xcode.

The problem is, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. I watched Youtube videos, read books & blogs. The problem still persists.

I've read a lot of posts in here, you're welcomed to post a link to one of them but I probably have seen it already..

can anyone let me know if they've had a similar issue?

Comment: You might want to change the title to something more descriptive and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did list all the required steps before please let me know which one you are missing and I can explain it in details.

check my answer to this question please.
[Ad-hoc distribution in XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917848/ad-hoc-distribution-in-xcode-4)

Edit: Please make sure to create the **Entitlement.plist** like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>CEQL88X2X2.com.company.appname</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then go to the project settings and fix it like so in the image below:
[image]

Comment: I think the issue now is that whenever I try to sign it, it always says:
"iPhone Distribution: (no profiles currently match)"
I installed both the certificate and profile and installed them

Comment: Did you create a new App in www.itunesconnect.com which is binded to the App Id you created in the provisioning profile portal ?

Comment: Did you create entitlement.plist file and added the App ID including the first 10 strange characters <seed number> ?

Comment: the App ID I created doesn't appear when creating a new app. Only the "WildCard" ID does. Also I might need help creating the entitlement list.

Comment: Check my edits on how to set the entitlement.plist
1- Create a new file Entitlement.plist then follow the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Yeah I'll be coming to that in a minute. I'm actually stuck at this:
http://imgur.com/vCKOX

Neither options give me a chance to continue

Comment: @HussainAl-Ismail "the App ID I created doesn't appear when creating a new app. Only the "WildCard" ID does." That sounds like a problem in itself...  Are you positive the certificate is valid?

Comment: I just created the certificate, on the portal it says "vaild", is there any other way I can check its validity?