# Can I distribute a test through testflight without creating my application on iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I'd like to send a demo of my application to someone through TestFlight.

I've been following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917884/555690

Eventually, you see this:

> login to iTunes Connect and create the App details

Do I have to create my App in iTunes Connect now? I don't think I have sufficient info/details yet. Also, I heard that when you create the app, you have to upload the binary within certain timeframe (six months?), or you will be forced to make a different iTunes Connect app entry.

Comment: Yes you can. You have to use the old http://testflightapp.com from before Apple bought the company and started integrating it s services. You still have to create an account there and so do all your testers. See this for a quick demo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcueNVIBlXw and this for uploading the IPA file http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXl3MjVGNf8 and this on how to install the app on your devices http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEbxBV9xlzU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to create it in iTunes Connect, but you do need to create it in the [Apple iOS Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

Comment: Yes you can. You have to use the old testflightapp.com from before Apple bought the company and started integrating it s services. You still have to create an account there and so do all your testers. See this for a quick demo youtube.com/watch?v=XcueNVIBlXw

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to login on iTunes Connect and add details.

You need to login to developer.apple.com -> Member Center -> Create Ad hoc distribution profile -> Create build -> Upload to test-flight.

Hope this info helps you..