# When sending a demo through TestFlight, do I have to create a new archive whenever I get a new tester?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight

I am going to send a demo of my project through TestFlight to someone.

To do so, I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917884/555690, but I did something else as well: I asked for his device UDID and then added the device on my Apple Developer portal. After that, I created my distribution provisioning profile selecting such device...

... now someone else is probably going to test too. And other people as well.

I fear that I might have to add their devices to my Apple Developer portal, re-configure the provisioning profile, and then re-create the archive all over again.

Is this correct, or is it unnecessary to add their devices to my portal (and thus creating a new archive would also be unncessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to update a build every time you want to add  new tester. It is quite easy to add new tester for the existing build, all you have to do is add the device to your provisioning profile in ADC for your app. Then, download the profile to your computer. Now, comes the moment of truth. Go to the build, in testflight, to which you want to add tester. Then, in the left hand side you will see Permission tab,click there and then it will show you the profile and all the tester who currently have access to the build. Now, update the build with the one you downloaded earlier and then you will see the device in your list. Click on checkbox to turn the permission for the device and voila you're done. You could now distribute the same build to the tester.

Comment: "easy" and "provisioning" should not be allowed in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to add them to the profile in the dev portal each time, however testflight has a button, under Permissions, to update the profile for a build.
You can try uploading your new provisioning profile without having to archive and upload a new build.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow any of the following steps whichever suits you but in my experience I would recommend Process 1 as I have found this more reliable.

Process 1:

1. You have the UDID of the tester.
2. Using ADP, add the UDID in the devices list and create a new provisioning profile.
3. Download the profile and update the same in you project.
4. Build and archive a new ipa.
5. Upload it to testflight.

Process 2:

1. Using ADP, create a new provisioning provile.
2. Download the profile and upload it in your testflight account in permissions tab.
3. refresh and you would receive an updated list of usrs on your provisoning profile.
4. Select the users and Voila you are ON.

What i have experienced while trying Process 2 is that sometimes when you try to download the app, it displays " you dont have permission to download" or "unable to download at this time" even though the user is present in the provsioning profile.

A work-around fix for this issue is that whenever you upload a new build or a provisioning profile, always clear the cahce or in exterme cases, logout and log back in.

Hope this helps.